# Workbooks.Open display two different formats

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem when trying to read the content of two .CSV files with VBA. Both files are structured like this:

```
<Column 1>    <Column 2>    <Column 3>
<Data 1.1>    <Data 2.1>    <Data 3.1>
<Data 1.2>    <Data 2.2>    <Data 3.2>
<Data 1.3>    <Data 2.3>    <Data 3.3>
```

When I use `Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FILEPATH, ReadOnly:=True)` but I do not get the same format inside the files.

This is what I read in the first file: everything is in the column 1 and separated with semicolons.

```
<           Column 1           >
<Data 1.1>;<Data 2.1>;<Data 3.1>
<Data 1.2>;<Data 2.2>;<Data 3.2>
<Data 1.3>;<Data 2.3>;<Data 3.3>
```

This is what I read in the second file: everything stay normal.

```
<Column 1>    <Column 2>    <Column 3>
<Data 1.1>    <Data 2.1>    <Data 3.1>
<Data 1.2>    <Data 2.2>    <Data 3.2>
<Data 1.3>    <Data 2.3>    <Data 3.3>
```

I would love to open both file and read the data the same way in both. What am I doing wrong ? Is it something with my code or from one of the .CSV file ?

### Code Snippet

```
Public Sub openCSVFiles()

    Dim openWb1 As Workbook
    Dim openWb2 As Workbook

    Set openWb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FILEPATH_1, ReadOnly:=True, Delimiter:=";")
    Set openWb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FILEPATH_2, ReadOnly:=True, Delimiter:=";")

    'Cell A2 contains <Data 1.1>
    For Each dataRow In openWb1.Sheets(1).Range("A1:C3")
        Debug.Print dataRow
    Next dataRow

    'Cell A2 contains <Data 1.1>;<Data 2.1>;<Data 3.1>
    For Each dataRow In openWb2.Sheets(1).Range("A1:C3")
        Debug.Print dataRow
    Next dataRow

    openWb1.Close False
    openWb2.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Close both CSVs then 1. Run Text to columns on any populated cell with Delimited, turn on tab and semi-colon, finish. 2. Go back and run your code.

Comment: An easy alternative is to use replace function on 'dataRow', if you only want to print it. Other option is to use delimiter while opening -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel

Comment: @Jeeped Hi Jeeped, I opened both of my CSV files and did the manipulation you told me on all populated columns. This still doesn't solve my problem and both files are still containing data as I showed in my example.

Comment: @shash Hi shash, I want to do more than just displaying dataRow, I displayed it as an example in my question to do not show code not related to my error and keep it simple. I will try the delimiter argument while opening my file.

Comment: That isn't what I said at all. With both CSVs closed, you need to add the semi-colon to the default delimiters. If both CSVs subsequently open correctly then your inital stateent of *'Both files are structured like this'* would be wrong.

Comment: Is it possible, that these CSVs are different? Like one uses comma, and the other semicolon?

Comment: @shash - My money is that one is tabs, the other is semi-colon.

Comment: @shash How do I know if it uses comma or semicolon? I edited something in m code using delimiter but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Open it with Notepad

Comment: @shash When I open with notepad I can see data separated with semicolons in one file and I see a lot of special characters in the second file. I tried using the `Delimiter:=";"` in my code but it still doesn't work

Comment: @shash @Jeeped I found a solution! I changed `Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FILEPATH_1, ReadOnly:=True)` with `Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FILEPATH_1, ReadOnly:=True, Delimiter:=";", Local:=True)` and this works. Thank you very much to both of you!

Comment: That usually works for me. Anyway, you have some other option here. 1. Use Split() function , 2. use text to columns through VBA https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-texttocolumns-method-excel.

Comment: @Teasel Post it as answer so this question will be marked as answered. Thanks! :)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I will, just give me time to write a good one haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when you face such an issue the first step is to get a quick glance at the file using Notepad. Once you know what the delimiter(s) is/are, use one of the following based on your need

1. Use Split() function with the delimiter
2. Use Replace() function when only printing/display is needed
3. Define a delimiter while opening -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel
4. Use 'Text to Columns' with VBA - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-texttocolumns-method-excel

Comment: I accepted your answer since it is the most likely to help people. Thank you again for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter the same issue, this could be a solution. The problem was that the delimiter wasn't the same, to avoid this problem we must specify the delimiter when opening the file.

```
'Replace this
Set openWb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FILEPATH_1, ReadOnly:=True)
Set openWb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FILEPATH_2, ReadOnly:=True

'By this
Set openWb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FILEPATH_1, _
                             ReadOnly:=True, _
                             Delimiter:=YourDelimiterHere)

Set openWb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FILEPATH_2, _
                             ReadOnly:=True, _
                             Delimiter:=YourDelimiterHere)
```

I specified the `Delimiter` argument. [You can find more information about it here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel).